# How do I use Assassin's Creed DLC in another profile?

Tags: psn, assassins-creed-2

I got some of the DLCs ( bonfires of vanities, etc ) and installed them in one profile, now I can't access them in another profile that I had. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, if everything is on the same PS3, it should not have any problem, even if it's on two different profiles. I do not own Assassins Creed, but for many other games, I have no problem between profiles.

If you really have a problem, you should maybe think about re-download the DLC.

Answer (score -1):

- search for saved position by other people
- call the support or mail Ubisoft

There links might help:

- http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=409956
- http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110507222120AAvf1Dy